# Travis: how to matrix install: sudo apt-add-repository

Tags: travis-ci

In Travis, how do I build a matrix, the only difference between the builds being one `install:` command. I want two builds, one for each of:

`- sudo add-apt-repository http://qgis.org/debian-ltr`

`- sudo add-apt-repository http://qgis.org/debian`

I can't get the .travis.yml syntax right. My config is here, for reference:

https://github.com/tomchadwin/qgis2web/blob/master/.travis.yml

Answer (score 0):

Answered elsewhere:

`env:
  - QGIS_REPO=http://qgis.org/debian-ltr
  - QGIS_REPO=http://qgis.org/debian
install:
  - sudo add-apt-repository ${QGIS_REPO}`